# Drag and Drop in Pantheon Files Using Left Click?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files

I'm new in Linux, I just install Elementary OS, the weird thing is the pantheon files behavior, it's using right click and drag, to drag and drop item. How I change it to left click? thank you

Comment: Actually it should work with both left and right click, isn't it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to System Settings/Mouse and Touchpad.  There you can change which button is "primary" and which is "secondary".  By default, the left button is "primary" and using this for drag and drop performs the default operation (copy or move) depending on the source and destination.  Using the secondary button (usually right), gives you a menu when you drop allowing a choice of Copy, Move, Link and Cancel.

If the behaviour is not as expected, check whether other applications are also affected.  If so it may be a hardware problem.